# Sorting an array of arrays with the delta

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, multidimensional-array, quicksort

I have an array like this:

```
[[300, 400], [200, 300], [500, 600], [400, 200]]
```

Which I want is to make an another array sorted by other value and the first item should be closer to that value, I tried to sort by delta:

```
c = [300, 50]
f = [[200, 300], [300, 400], [400, 200], [500, 600]].sort do |a, b|
  a_width_delta = a.first - c.first
  a_height_delta = a.last - c.last
  b_width_delta = b.first - c.first
  b_height_delta = b.last - c.last

  (a_width_delta + a_height_delta) <=> (b_width_delta + b_height_delta)
end
p "Input #{c}"
p f
c = [300, 400]
f = [[200, 300], [300, 400], [400, 200], [500, 600]].sort do |a, b|
  a_width_delta = a.first - c.first
  a_height_delta = a.last - c.last
  b_width_delta = b.first - c.first
  b_height_delta = b.last - c.last

  (a_width_delta + a_height_delta) <=> (b_width_delta + b_height_delta)
end
p "Input #{c}"
p f
```

This conditional is correct:

```
$> ruby fo.rb
"Input [300, 50]"
[[200, 300], # other elements] # correct!
```

Another one is wrong:

```
"Input [300, 400]"
[[200, 300], # other elements] # wrong!
```

It should be:

```
"Input [300, 400]"
[[300, 400], # other elements] # correct!
```

All that I need is an array with closest value at the first index.

Comment: I can't come up with a set of rules that would produce your "correct" result for the second example. E.g., why does `[500, 600]` appear before `[200, 300]`?

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do... `[500, 600]` has a difference of `200+200=400`, which is higher than `[200, 300]`, which has a difference of `100+100=200`.

Comment: My bad, it's little vague, all that I need  it's sorted array with the closest value at the first index. I can't get how sorting should look, so I've tried sort by delta.

Comment: Then in your code, why are you looking at the second index? Why last correct output is correct? Could you provide some explanation as it's hard to understand what exactly you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm hoping your example of "correct" output is just wrong. Otherwise I don't understand the requirements. :-)

If I do understand correctly, the idea is to sort by the "distance" of each element from a starting point. The distance is defined as the sum of the differences of the component values. E.g. for `x1, y1` and `x2, y2`: `|x2-x1| + |y2-y1|`.

It's the absolute value that's missing... your current code "rewards" negative numbers inappropriately.

Here's a version that takes the absolute value of each calculation. It doesn't produce your desired output. If you really do want the output you specified, please describe what rules you're using to determine that.

```
c = [300, 50]
f = [[200, 300], [300, 400], [400, 200], [500, 600]].sort do |a, b|
  a_width_delta = (a.first - c.first).abs
  a_height_delta = (a.last - c.last).abs
  b_width_delta = (b.first - c.first).abs
  b_height_delta = (b.last - c.last).abs

  (a_width_delta + a_height_delta) <=> (b_width_delta + b_height_delta)
end
p "Input #{c}"
p f

# Output:
# "Input [300, 50]"
# [[400, 200], [200, 300], [300, 400], [500, 600]]


c = [300, 400]
f = [[200, 300], [300, 400], [400, 200], [500, 600]].sort do |a, b|
  a_width_delta = (a.first - c.first).abs
  a_height_delta = (a.last - c.last).abs
  b_width_delta = (b.first - c.first).abs
  b_height_delta = (b.last - c.last).abs

  (a_width_delta + a_height_delta) <=> (b_width_delta + b_height_delta)
end
p "Input #{c}"
p f

# Output:
# "Input [300, 400]"
# [[300, 400], [200, 300], [400, 200], [500, 600]]
```

**EDIT**

Per the edit to your question, it seems that all you care about is the first element in the output array (the minimum). In that case, why not just calculate the min?

```
c = [300, 50]
f = [[200, 300], [300, 400], [400, 200], [500, 600]].min_by { |x| (x.first - c.first).abs + (x.last - c.last).abs }
p "Input #{c}"
p f

# Output:
# "Input [300, 50]"
# [400, 200]


c = [300, 400]
f = [[200, 300], [300, 400], [400, 200], [500, 600]].min_by { |x| (x.first - c.first).abs + (x.last - c.last).abs }
p "Input #{c}"
p f

# Output:
# "Input [300, 400]"
# [300, 400]
```

Comment: The second output procedure another result with `[400, 200]` at the first index.

Comment: What? Are you saying you get different output than what I did? Or something else?

Comment: Based on your edit to your question, I added a solution using `min_by`.

Answer (score 1):

```
▶ λ = lambda do |input, point|
    [input, point].transpose # to ease the subtraction
                  .map { |e| e.reduce &:- } # distances [x, y]
                  .map(&:abs) # absolute values of distances
                  .reduce(:+) # total distance
  end

▶ [[200, 300], [300, 400], [400, 200], [500, 600]].min_by &λ.curry[[300, 50]]
#⇒ [400, 200]

▶ [[200, 300], [300, 400], [400, 200], [500, 600]].min_by &λ.curry[[300, 400]]
#⇒ [300, 400]
```